# PHP - get nearest date for input of 'dd.mm'

Tags: php

When having a date string in the format `dd.mm.` without a year-part, what's the best way to get the most logical (nearest to today) `dd.mm.yyyy` string?

Examples:

`nDate('06.06.') === '06.06.2014'` // '06.06.2014' is nearer to '14.03.2014' then '06.06.2013'

`nDate('10.12.') === '10.12.2013'` // '10.12.2013' is nearer to '14.03.2014' then '10.12.'2014'

My current code:

```
function nDate($date) {
    $tmpDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $date . date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')));
    foreach ($years as $year) {
        $tmpDate2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $date . $year);
        if ($tmpDate2 instanceof DateTime && (!($tmpDate instanceof DateTime) || abs($tmpDate2->getTimeStamp() - time()) < abs($tmpDate->getTimeStamp() - time()))) {
            $tmpDate = $tmpDate2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @putvande I added 2 examples.

Comment: Please tell what I can improve about the question when downvoting / close-voting :(

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you didn't show any of your tries.

Comment: @dragoste Well, I sure thought of creating full dates for previous/current/next year and comparing the differences to the current date. That's just rather clunky! I thought that there might be a function which already does this.

Comment: That's just a few lines of code

Answer (score -1):

1. For given month and day create full dates for previous, current and next year.
2. Choose the one of the first three that has least difference betweeen that date and current date.

You can do that with `strtotime` function.

**Edit:**

It could be like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @param string $srcDate format mm-dd
 */
function closestDate($srcDate) {
    $dates['prev'] = (date('Y') - 1) . '-' . $srcDate;
    $dates['curr'] = date('Y') . '-' . $srcDate;
    $dates['next'] = (date('Y') + 1) . '-' . $srcDate;

    $times = array_map('strtotime', $dates);
    $diffs = array_map(function($time) {
        return abs($time - strtotime('today'));
    }, $times);

    $minDiff = min($diffs);
    $key = array_keys($diffs, $minDiff);
    return $dates[$key[0]];
}

echo closestDate('06-06'); //2014-06-06
echo closestDate('12-10'); //2013-12-10
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an implementation?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Next time first try something on your own. We're here to help solving problems, but not to solve your problems as a whole.